# Haskell - Couldn't match type `(Int, Integer)' with `Pos'

Tags: haskell

I am currently learning Haskell and I am currently having an issue.

This is my code:

```
data Pos = Pos (Int, Int) deriving (Show, Eq)                             
allCoordinates :: [Pos]
allCoordinates = concat [(zip (allHelper x) [0..8]) | x<-[0..8]]

allHelper ::Int -> [Int]
allHelper x = [x | y<-[0..8]]
```

I have to use that specific data type and I am having a little issue due to this.

This code works perfectly fine if the code is written like this:

```
type Pos = (Int, Int)
allCoordinates :: [(Int, Int)]
allCoordinates = concat [(zip (allHelper x) [0..8]) | x<-[0..8]]
```

but  I need to edit this bit:

```
concat [(zip (allHelper x) [0..8]) | x<-[0..8]]
```

so that it works with:

```
allCoordinates :: [Pos]
```

It is probably a simple issue and I having a bit of a mental block however can anyone help?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you write:

```
type Pos = (Int, Int)
```

You have **not** constructed a new type: you have constructed a type alias, so you can interchange `Pos` with `(Int, Int)` in the code. So a function with signature `f :: [(Int,Int)]` is equivalent to `f :: [Pos]`.

You can clean up the code and write:

```
allCoordinates :: [Pos]
allCoordinates = [ (x,y) | x <- [0..8], y <- [0..8]]
```

Or even more clean (but probably somewhat harder to understand):

```
allCoordinates :: [Pos]
allCoordinates = (,) <$> [0..8] <*> [0..8]
```

A disadvantage of the fact that you work with a type signature is that there can be a lot of functions defined on that type, and perhaps you want to define functions with the *same name* (in case of type classes), but with a different implementation. In that case you can define a **datatype**:

```
data Pos = Pos (Int,Int)
```

Now we have defined a *new* type, with a constructor `Pos`. Now the above code will no longer work, but we can easily alter it by calling the constructor on the tuples we produce. So:

```
allCoordinates :: [Pos]
allCoordinates = [ Pos (x,y) | x <- [0..8], y <- [0..8]]
```

In case you define a type with *one* constructor and that constructor has *one* parameter, we can use `newtype`. Now we have defined a type, but Haskell can optimize it such that internally, it will not wrap and unwrap in a constructor, but simply treat the tuple in another way:

```
newtype Pos = Pos (Int,Int)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Has completely solved my issue!

Answer (score 1):

`type` defines a **Type alias**. That is to say, writing:

```
type Pos = (Int, Int)
```

means that whenever you write `Pos` in your code, the compiler sees `(Int, Int)`. To construct a `Pos` in this case, you can just write `(1, 2)`, since an `(Int, Int)` and a `Pos` are indistinguishable.

However, `data` defines a new datatype. Your example is:

```
data Pos = Pos (Int, Int)
```

`Pos` is a type constructed by the function `Pos :: (Int, Int) -> Pos`. **These are not equal**! To construct a `Pos` in this case, you would write `Pos (1, 2)`.

To correct your code, write:

```
data Pos = Pos (Int, Int)
allCoordinates :: [(Int, Int)]
allCoordinates = concat [zipWith (curry Pos) (allHelper x) [0..8] | x<-[0..8]]
```

Where `zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]`.

However, unless you want different behaviour in typeclasses, using a type alias would be best, otherwise, you should use a [newtype](https://wiki.haskell.org/Newtype).

Comment: I am now getting this error:  Couldn't match type `Pos' with `Integer -> (Int, Int)'
      Expected type: (Int, Int) -> Integer -> (Int, Int)
        Actual type: (Int, Int) -> Pos

Comment: @JamesHolliday My mistake. Replace `zipWith Pos` with `zipWith (curry Pos)`.